# Should I assign a formula field to text field in flow before the record is saved or after the record is saved?

Tags: visual-workflow, duplicate-management, order-of-execution, duplicate-value

I need to add Checkbox and Date field to matching rules - but Salesforce don't support such functionality - but I can add a text field to Matching rules
So I want to create a flow which will take a formula field (formula will take value from Checkbox and Date) and assign value from formula field to text field.

Should I use flow before the record is saved or after the record is saved?

Answer (score 3):

You should use `before the record is saved` in the flow.

First, it will not require DML to update field value, it works the same as before trigger.

Second, according to the [order of execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm):

```
...
4. Executes all before triggers.
...
6. Executes duplicate rules.
...
8. Executes all after triggers.
...
```